# Ionic 2 mobilefirst 8.0 adapter call not working in browser

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ionic2

I am invoking a procedure on mobilefirst 8.0 adapter from ionic 2
I am able to see the response in device but not in chrome.Got the below error
**ReferenceError: WLResourceRequest is not defined**.Below is my code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TransitPage } from '../transit/transit';
import { TrackDartPage } from '../track-dart/track-dart';
import { LocationFinderPage } from '../location-finder/location-finder';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
declare var WLResourceRequest;
calladapter(){
    var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/trackDart/status/" + 2,WLResourceRequest.GET);
    resourceRequest.send().then((response) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(response.responseText));
    },
    function(error){
       alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Does not display on the browser on desktop? Mobile browser? Please provide exact steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the error I suspect that you are running **ionic serve** which is leading you to this error since ionic does not know about MobileFirst. Instead, run **mfpdev app preview** after running **npm run watch** command.

Comment: Thanks Prerak Tiwari. I tried mfpdev app preview and able to get the result.